# Selenium WebDriver запуск группы тестов в одном экземпляре браузера

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation

Сейчас мои класс с тестами выглядит примерно так. То есть браузер запускается снова и снова для каждого теста
Можно ли как-то сделать так, что бы тесты выполнялись в одном окне браузера, без запуска новых экземпляров?

```
WebSite webSite;
Variable variable;
WebDriver webDriver;
WebDriverWait wait;

@BeforeClass
public static void setupClass() {
    WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
    WebDriver webDriver = new ChromeDriver();
    webDriver.get("");
}
@Before
public void preCondition(){
    variable = new Variable();
    webSite = new WebSite(webDriver);;
    wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, 30, 300);
    webDriver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
    webDriver.manage().window().maximize();
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().setScriptTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    webDriver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    webDriver.get("");
}

@Test
public void passwordLessThanMin(){
    webSite.registrationPage().Password.sendKeys(variable.lessThanMinPass);
    webSite.registrationPage().SignUpButton.click();
    Assert.assertTrue(webSite.registrationPage().Password.getAttribute("aria-invalid").contains("true"));
    Assert.assertTrue(webSite.registrationPage().AllertPassword.getText().contains("YOUR PASSWORD MUST BE AT LEAST 5 CHARACTERS LONG"));
}
    @After
    public void postCondition(){
            if(webDriver != null)
                webDriver.quit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Замените аннтоацию `@Before` и `@After` на `@BeforeClass` и `@AfterClass` соответственно.

Если метод помечен как `@Before` (`@After`), то этот метод будет вызываться каждый раз перед запуском(после прогона) теста.

Если же вы будете использовать `@BeforeClass` (`@AfterClass`), то метод, помеченный этой аннотацией, будет вызыва всего лишь один раз перед запуском ( после прогона) всех тестов.

Методы, помеченные `@BeforeClass` и `@AfterClass` должны быть статическими и не должны иметь параметров.